# Cloud Custodian: resources:ec2 not available in region

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, automation, cloudcustodian

I am using Cloud Custodian and policies written in YAML for automating tasks related with AWS. For now, I am trying to stop a running instance. Following is the policy, `custodian.yml`, that I am using:

```
policies:
  - name: my-first-policy
    resource: ec2
    filters:
      - "tag:test": present
    actions:
      - stop
```

The instance is tagged with tag `test`. And the location, where the instance is running is `us-east-2b`. I am using the following command to use the policy:

```
AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=us-east-2b AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID="the_value_of_the_key_ID" AWS_SECRET_KEY="the_value_of_secret_key"  custodian run --output-dir=. custodian.yml
```

The problem is that there are no errors/logs that are generated but it is unable to locate the instance and throws the following warning:

```
2017-06-17 08:28:17,926: c7n.policies:WARNING policy:my-first-policy resources:ec2 not available in region:us-east-2b
2017-06-17 08:28:17,927: custodian.commands:WARNING Empty policy file(s).  Nothing to do.
```

I am using the guidelines on working with Cloud Custodian from the following links:

```
http://www.capitalone.io/cloud-custodian/docs/quickstart/index.html#write-your-first-policy
http://www.capitalone.io/cloud-custodian/docs/quickstart/index.html#write-your-first-policy
```

Can somebody help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modify:

```
AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=us-east-2b
```

to:

```
AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=us-east-2
```

`us-east-2` is a region (US Ohio). `us-east-2b` is an availability zone.

Comment: I tried doing that as well. It throws the following error: PartialCredentialsError: Partial credentials found in env, missing: AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY

Comment: You are passing `AWS_SECRET_KEY` instead of `AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY`. Try changing that.